# AWS SQS always return 1 message (PHP SDK)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

Im getting trouble with receiveMessage function of AWS SQS. It always returns 1 random message

```
        $result = $client->receiveMessage(array(
            'MaxNumberOfMessages' => 10,
            'MessageAttributeNames' => ['All'],
            'QueueUrl' => AConfig::sqs_query_url, // REQUIRED
            'WaitTimeSeconds' => 10,
        ));
```

Please give a suggestion :(

And one more question: Do have anyways to filter message by sender_id?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because of the nature of AWS SQS. Your messages are not physical in one single queue they are spreaded in different queues internally.

Therefore the documentations says the following:

> [...] If the number of messages in the queue is small (fewer than
>   1,000), you most likely get fewer messages than you requested per
>   ReceiveMessage call. [...]

For more details please check the [AWS SQS - Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sqs-2012-11-05.html#receivemessage).

Comment: Thank for you answer, how about the filter? I cant find any function to do that :|

Comment: From my point of view this functionality doesnt exists. What are you trying to do? Maybe we can find a better alternative :-)

Comment: Im trying to get many many message to sync data from another system . Server A sends message to SQS, Server B will get and save Data, then resent that object with new status to SQS, SERVER A gets and check.

I want to send a big json data to SQS, but SQS only allows sending a max string length is 256KB.

If separating json to child messages, I have to do a looping to get all message, because SQS only responds few messages, not all messages => big request will be sent and I have to pay for it :|

Comment: I dont know if this is a common practice but you could do the following: Server A put the big json data into `S3`. On that bucket you have to setup `Events` which listens on `ObjectCreate` events and notifies a `SNS Topic`. Server B is subscribed to this `SNS Topic`. As soon as Server B is done with the processing of the data it notifies a different `SNS Topic` where Server A is subscribed.

Comment: I have the same problem using the Java API but I happen to have over 80k messages in the queue, so I guess it's not related to the short polling method.